# Create component and append to div

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive

I have a `<div>` with a directive `[appComponent]` so I can create a component and append to it.

```
<div [appComponent]="component">
```

My directive is as follows:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appComponent]'
})
export class ComponentDirective implements OnChanges {
  @Input('appComponent') comp: any;
  private container;

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {
    this.container = this.elementRef.nativeElement;
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    const newComponent = this.renderer.createElement('new-component');
    this.renderer.appendChild(this.container, newComponent);
  }
}
```

And my `new-component`:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'new-component',
  templateUrl: './new-component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./new-component.scss']
})
export class NewComponent {
}
```

This component has contents inside.
The element is created and appended to div, however, it's empty:

```
<div>
    <new-component _ngcontent-c3=""></new-component>
</div>
```

How to instantiate a component and append it to div?  I'm using angular 7.

Comment: What is your expected output? Kindly give a brief about what is inside `new-component.html`...

Comment: `new-component.html` only contains a text... it's `<div>Test</div>`

Comment: I answer this here for standalone components https://stackoverflow.com/a/76683173/1440240

Answer (score 2):

Try using `ViewContainerRef` and `ComponentFactoryResolver`,

```
let componentFactory = 
    this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(NewComponent);
let componentInstance = 
    this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
this.renderer.appendChild(this.container, 
    componentInstance.location.nativeElement);
```

Comment: How to append it to the `<div>`?

Comment: Use `componentInstance` to render it inside the `container`

Answer (score -1):

You don't need the `ElementRef` nor the `Renderer2` for this.

Try this instead:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appComponent]'
})
export class ComponentDirective implements OnChanges {
  @Input('appComponent') comp: any;

  constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver, public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) {
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(NewComponent);
    const componentRef = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
    this.viewContainerRef.insert(componentRef.hostView);
  }
}
```

One important thing to mention is, to make this work you have to add `NewComponent` to `entryComponents` as follows:

```
@NgModule({
  imports [...],
  entryComponents: [NewComponent],
  declarations: [NewComponent, ComponentDirective, ...],
  bootstrap: [...]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Here is a working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dbszef